# Overlay drawable with color on state

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have the following `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/like_button"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_like"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num_likes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

The `ic_like` drawable is simply a gray-colored thumbs-up icon. Is there a way to change the color of the icon during a specific state without supplying the same icon PNG in a different color and instead supplying a hex color value for the icon to change to?

For example, how can I create a list of states where, if the icon is clicked, the icon's color changes to red?

Comment: see `Drawable#setColorFilter`

Comment: How would I create the different states (since, to my knowledge, they're normally set in a separate XML layout)?

Comment: I think Fontastica may help you https://github.com/Tawreh/fontastica

Comment: just call `setColorFilter` whenever you want to change the color

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this with png drawable resources, but you can create differents .png icons and then use it from your code

yourImageView.setImageResources(..your icon..);